# PHP : setting up login time in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've to setup  login time in db , this is how i'm doing it .

every login in first login if there is no value for today. login  field   is of DateTime type ,Now when we add a new user from admin panel i only add  username , password and email and that user is automatically assigned NULL in logged in  field ,when i try to update that does not get updated , see my code

```
function user_login($connection, $email, $password){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM  employees WHERE email='$email' and password='$password' ";
        $query= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);          
        $result =  mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($result==1){
            $_SESSION["login_user"]=$email; 
            header("LOCATION:userhome.php");
            login_time($email);
        }
        else{
            header("LOCATION:login.php");
        }
    } 


function  login_time($email){ 
        global $connection; 
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email='$email'";  
        $query= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        $loggedin=$result["loggedin"];    
        if($loggedin==NULL){
            $updatequery= "UPDATE employees set loggedin=NOW() ";
            $update= mysqli_query($connection, $updatequery);
        }
    }
```

I expect it to be updated, but it does not.

Comment: I see a big problem, but that should update all rows in employees table with the time now()

Comment: i  know  and i would set that email , but  now i've only 2 records

Comment: What about your $connection variable? In first function you passed it with params in the second you used global? Can you show us how you set up connection and call the functions?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `WHERE` statement

```
UPDATE employees set loggedin=NOW()
```

That will update ALL records to the current time

```
UPDATE employees SET 
     loggedin=NOW() 
WHERE email='$email'
```

I hope for your sake that `$email` is sanitized.

Comment: sir thats not the  the issue i'm just testing it against  2 records so please if you help me to fix time issue .